# Inserting HTML using Jquery (Limiting amount of times)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to insert a snippet of HTML code after each feed item using JQuery, however whatever I try it still doesn't work. I have displayed the HTML code below of the page I am trying to edit. I am trying to get some HTML to be inserted after every feed time (every time it finishes with  `class="wp_rss_retriever_container">`)

```
<div class="wp_rss_retriever">
    <ul class="wp_rss_retriever_list">
        <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
            <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper">
                <a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/uncategorized/man-united-ready-to-smash-transfer-record-to-sign-star-striker/" title="Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker">
                    Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker
                </a>

                <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">

                    <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata">
                        <span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">
                            Published: March 25, 2016 - 12:29 pm
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
            <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper">
                <a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/fenerbahce-plan-bid-for-manchester-united-ace-mata/" title="Fenerbahce plan bid for Manchester United ace Mata">
                    Fenerbahce plan bid for Manchester United ace Mata
                </a>

                <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">

                    <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata">
                        <span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">
                            Published: March 25, 2016 - 12:15 pm
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
            <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper">
                <a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/united-arsenal-target-morata-premier-league-would-suit-me/" title="Manchester United, Arsenal target Morata: Premier League would suit me">
                    Manchester United, Arsenal target Morata: Premier League would suit me
                </a>
                <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">

                    <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata">
                        <span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">
                            Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:55 am
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
            <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper">
                <a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/manchester-united-rival-arsenal-liverpool-for-juventus-striker-morata/"
```

The code i tried to use to get it to work is

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter( ".wp_rss_retriever_container" );
```

Comment: I do not see any JS Code in Fiddle.

Comment: Other than *"3 times"* it's hard to make any sense out of what the specific problem is here. Also no idea what *"however it is ever changing"* means or how it relates to problem

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated the original question so i makes more sense

Comment: Basic code shown works fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/peggm5v7/1/

Comment: @charlietfl Is there anyway to modify that code to limit it, eg condition and break

Comment: Can keep a count each time you add it. Still not clear how it gets added since no context provided

Answer (score 0):

You could use each to iterate over all the .wp_rss_retriever_container class:

```
$('.wp_rss_retriever_container').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).append("<p>Test</p>"); //or .html()
});
```

If you want it to be 'limited amount of times' you could condition and break if 'i' is equal to some value:

```
if(i == 5){ break; }  // only 4 'test' will be added
```

Hope it helps to you!